# ReactJS: run function on prop change without using deprecated componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a container component which gets page number as prop and downloads data for that page. I rely on `componentDidUpdate()` to trigger the download as `componentDidUpdate()` fires when `pageNumber` changes. Is this a reasonable way to do it?

One thing I noticed is that the component gets re-rendered when it receives a new `pageNumber` even though nothing changes at first and then it re-renders again once data has been downloaded. The first re-render is superfluous. Should I not be bothered by this?

If I was really bothered, I could user `shouldComponentUpdate()` to only re-render when `data` changes. (I wonder if this check might even be more costly than the re-render itself?) However, if I used `shouldComponentUpdate()` and not update on page change, then I couldn't rely on `componentDidUpdate()` to load my data anymore.

Does this mean that the below is the way to do it or is there a better way?

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Table from "../components/Table";
import Pagination from "../components/Pagination";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {changePage} from "../js/actions";


const PAGE_COUNT = 10;

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { currentPage: state.currentPage }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    changePage: page => dispatch(changePage(page))
  };
};

class ConnectedTableContainer extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: [],
        loaded: false,
    };

    handlePageChange = page => {
        if (page < 1 || page > PAGE_COUNT) return;
        this.props.changePage(page);
    };

    loadData = () => {
        this.setState({ loaded: false });
        const { currentPage } = this.props;
        const pageParam = currentPage ? "?_page=" + currentPage : "";
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + pageParam)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    console.log("Unexpected response: " + response.status);
                    return;
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => this.setState({
                data: data,
                loaded: true,
            }))
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadData(this.props.currentPage);

    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       if (prevProps.currentPage != this.props.currentPage) {
            this.loadData();
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { loaded } = this.state;
        const { currentPage } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="section">
                    <Pagination onPageChange={ this.handlePageChange } pageCount={ PAGE_COUNT } currentPage={ currentPage }/>
                </div>
                <div className={ "section " + (loaded ? "" : "loading") }>
                    <Table data={ this.state.data } />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ConnectedTableContainer.propTypes = {
    changePage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    currentPage: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

ConnectedTableContainer.defaultProps = {
    currentPage: 1,
};

const TableContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedTableContainer);

export default TableContainer;
```

Comment: When Ever the setState() method is called the render function get called  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033950/7865621   This may give a some idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use `componentDidUpdate()` to trigger the download when `pageNumber` changes.

I would not recommend to implement `shouldComponentUpdate`, instead inherit from `React.PureComponent`. This implements `shouldComponentUpdate` for you by comparing props and state. If any of the props and state change (shallow comparison), it'll re-render, otherwise not.